# Products on category pages keep disappearing until reindex

Tags: magento2, category, category-products, reindex

The products on my website in the category achieves pages keep disappearing and I have to run indexer reindex every 24 hours or so. I tried both Reindex by schedule and Update on save but the problem persists. What I see on the website is ‘No products found for this category.’

Comment: Which magento version you are using?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX: Changing the value of Elasticsearch Index Prefix in Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search to another value fixes the problem as stated here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/elasticsearch/configure-magento.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to confirm that your Elastic Search configure properly and running properly as well.

Comment: ```curl localhost``` returns the following output which confirms it is running properly: 
{
  "name" : "ip-123-45-67-89",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "lclGCCCXXXXV5YfrRGg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.15.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "93d5a7f643casd23f123f4fb81bf6fa7309da0c",
    "build_date" : "2021-11-04T14:04:42.515624022Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    ....
What additional configurations can I check? Also, I am running two magento websites on same Elasticsearch.